# Received generic error message when running Initialize-ADDeviceRegistration

Tags: powershell

I am working on setting up work folders for one of my customers. I have followed the steps given in [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747208(v=ws.11).aspx) on TechNet. However, I am receiving a very generic error when attempting to run the PowerShell cmdlet `Initialize-ADDeviceRegistration`. All it is telling me is

> A value in the request is invalid.

Here is a screenshot of the full error message:

[image: Powershell Error]

Answer (score 0):

`CORP\WorkFolders$` is a **computer** account. You can't use that as a service account. Create and use a dedicated **user** account instead.

Comment: The account that I am attempting to use is a Managed Service Account instead of a computer or user account.  I did attempt earlier with the normal admin credentials and was still not able to initialize.